# Stop other classes from adding to lists with "private set;"

Tags: c#, list

Currently, I have a class (classB) that has a list --v

```
class classB
{
    public List<int> alist { get; private set; }
...
```

And I can accessing this class from another class (classA)

```
ClassB foo = new ClassB();
        foo.alist.Add(5);
```

Question is, can I stop this from happening?  (make it unchangeable from other classes) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just expose the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface:

```
private List<int> alist;

public IReadOnlyList<int> Alist 
{
    get { return this.alist; }
}
```

From inside of the class, you continue to use "alist", to add/remove elements. From outside of the class you can only access "Alist", which doesn't allow to modify the collection (unless explicitly cast).

Comment: In addition to this answer you could also avoid exposing the list to the outside and just offer a public method on your class called AddToAList(int item).

Comment: @StefanCh This is what I'm currently doing, but I still need a way access the list from the outside...

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are various options here.

- You could change the property type to one which only provides a read-only interface (e.g. `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. That doesn't stop the caller from casting the returned reference back to `List<T>` though.
- You could create a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to wrap your real list, and only expose that - that wrapper will prevent the caller from being able to access the real list at all (other than by reflection)
- If *your* code doesn't need to modify the collection either, you could *just* keep the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapper, or use the [immutable collections package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx)
- You could avoid exposing the list at all, perhaps implementing `IEnumerable<T>` within your class

It really depends on exactly what your requirements are.

Comment: I really only need a way to make sure someone don't accidentally change the values individually (I have 2 values I want to change together), so the first option is fine, thanks for the other options though :)

Comment: @HandofC'thuhlu: If your list always has two values, are you sure it's appropriate for it to be a list rather than just a type encapsulating those two values?

Comment: Yeah, it probably is best to do that. but this is just a tiny project I'm working on, so I'm not really too worried about it at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion though.